# SQLite: Query returning old/cached data

Tags: android, sqlite

We've got an activity that a list of items and their statuses.  When the user clicks on the item, another activity launches where the user can perform certain tasks that change the status of that item.  When the activity finishes and the previous one resumes, the items and their statuses are queried from the database and listed (the query basically does a count(*), so it should find the record that was just inserted).

The problem is some users have been reporting that sometimes the item aren't updated, so they go back and perform the task again resulting in duplicate transactions which should not be possible under normal circumstances (we can confirm this from the data on the server).

For some reason I cannot replicate the behaviour at all (on an actual device and emulator).  But we know the query is returning old data because of user feedback and the data we receive.  By my estimate it happens around 3% of the time.

Does this have to do with a SQLite setting, or is there a bug in our code?

This is basically what the code does:

```
// Insert new record
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

processContentForDeviceStock(contentValues, object);

db.insert("table", null, contentValues);
db.close();

new AlertDialog.Builder(
    CurrentActivity.this)
    .setTitle("Success")
    .setMessage("Insert succesful")
    .setPositiveButton("OK",
        new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(
                    DialogInterface dialog,
                    int which) {
                setResult(RESULT_OK);
                // We are done, go back to the previous activity
                finish();
            }
        }).create().show();
```

When the List activity resumes:

```
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
Cursor res =  db.rawQuery(listQuery, null);
res.moveToFirst();

while(!res.isAfterLast()) {
    // Build our item list
    /*
    ...
    */
    res.moveToNext();
}

res.close();
db.close();

// List the items and their statuses
/*
...
*/
```

There is also a background thread that runs and attempts to read/update in the background.

The biggest issue for me is that there are no indications of an error anywhere.  SQLite reports that all transactions succeed and that errors, locking or otherwise, have occurred.

Update:

We've come across exactly the same bug in a different application.  We can see the data is being duplicated because of what is sent to the server, but we cannot tell for sure if the problem is that the data isn't being updated or that Sqlite is returning old data.  One change that we made is ensuring only one database connection that is accessible from all threads.

Here is the code that performs the update:

```
// Validation and column index handling code omitted
public long updateOrInsertUserTransaction(ArrayList<UserTransaction> entityList) {

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    String sql = "INSERT OR REPLACE INTO UserTransaction(UniqueId, TransType, " +
            "TransSubtype, TransDate, UserId, StockId, NumericValue, StringValue, " +
            "Latitude, Longitude, Accuracy, Comment, synched, deliveryattempts, firstdeliveryattempt)" +
            " VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?);";

    db.beginTransaction();

    SQLiteStatement stmt = db.compileStatement(sql);
    for (int i = 0; i < entityList.size(); i++) {
        UserTransaction entity = entityList.get(i);

        stmt.bindString(0 entity.getUniqueId());
        stmt.bindLong(1 entity.getTransType());

        if (entity.getTransSubtype() != null)
            stmt.bindLong(2, entity.getTransSubtype());

        stmt.bindString(3, entity.getTransDate());
        if (entity.getUserId() != null)
            stmt.bindLong(4, entity.getUserId());

        if (entity.getStockId() != null)
            stmt.bindLong(5, entity.getStockId());

        if (entity.getNumericValue() != null)
            stmt.bindDouble(6, entity.getNumericValue());

        String stringValue;
        if ((stringValue = entity.getStringValue()) != null)
            stmt.bindString(7, stringValue);

        stmt.bindDouble(8, entity.getLatitude());
        stmt.bindDouble(9, entity.getLongitude());
        stmt.bindDouble(10, entity.getAccuracy());

        if (entity.getComment() != null)
            stmt.bindString(11, entity.getComment());

        stmt.bindLong(12, entity.synched);
        stmt.bindLong(13, entity.deliveryattempts);

        if (entity.firstdeliveryattempt != null)
            stmt.bindString(14, entity.firstdeliveryattempt);

        stmt.execute();
        stmt.clearBindings();
    }

    db.setTransactionSuccessful();
    db.endTransaction();

    // Database is closed elsewhere via a Singleton

    Log.i(TAG, "updateOrInsertUserTransaction() - " + entityList.size());

    return entityList.size();
}
```

Comment: Did you solved your issue?

Comment: Not yet, unfortunately.  We suspect it may be related to a custom firmware that was released by the manufacturer.

Comment: Did you solved this issue

Comment: From your code the loop that builds the list view, while seeming simple, sounds like you don't dirty the view. If that is indeed your code, when there is no data in the db, it just leaves the old view around. So the result would be an old view representing old data but the on click listeners still fire when clicked